# Javascript regex to match a person's height

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex pattern to match a person's height to check if the input is valid. Here are some sample input:

5' 9"

6'

5'8"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make sure that no one mucks around with it, you could limit it to sensible ranges, eg: 3' to 7'11''

```
/^(3-7)'(?:\s*(?:1[01]|0-9)(''|"))?$/
```

I always thought that the "inches" mark was a double quote (`"`), compared to VonC's answer where he put it as two single quotes (`''`), so this regex takes both into consideration.

Comment: It is... " (Quote) for inches.  Up-voted for sensible range functionality in your regex.

Comment: should this be /^[3-7]'(?:\s*(?:1[01]|[0-9])(''|"))?$/ ? The given expression (3-7) and (0-9) doesn't work. I have to change it to [3-7] and [0-9]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
^(\d{1,5})\'((\s?)(-?)(\s?)([0-9]|(1[0-1]))\")?$
```

see: [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/155257a63c7a2cc6)

Comment: Nice copy/paste, but inappropriate here because we don't need 5 digits to represent the number of feet a *person* is tall.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
\d'(?:\s*\d+'')?
```

The second part refers to optional part of the heigth.

Remove the + if you want only one digit.

```
\b\d'(?:\s*\d+'')?\b
```

can also be used to detect that pattern within a text (avoid detecting 1234'45 as an heigth for... a person?!)

You can test that regexp [here for javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thanks for all your input. Wow, that was fast, Big time.

Anyway, I've tested all your regex and it seems Ruben's answer passed all my test input. Thanks a lot for that mate.

So here's the one that I need:

> ^(\d{1,5})\'((\s?)(-?)(\s?)([0-9]|(1[0-1]))\")?$

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d'\s?(\d{1,2}")?$
```

Tested here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html